# Can Excel produce a strange but logical sequence of numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got this pattern in Excel:

```
14
16
17
19
21
22
24
26
27
29
31
32
34
36
37
39
41
42
44
46
47
49
51
52
54
56
57
59
61
62
```

The logic to it is +2, +2, +1, rinse and repeat.  But when I try to extend the pattern, Excel will start simply counting.

How can I continue this pattern? My list continues until around 700.

Comment: You can define your own formula with that logic, which refers to the cell above. E. g. something like `=A1+2` in cell `B1` and so on which will lead to all odd numbers.

Comment: That wont work because I'll still have to do a manual count :S

Comment: What do you mean with "manual count"? What is the logic of your counting? When you can't define your logic, how should a program can do this for you?

Comment: @IQV: To be honest, on an IQ test this wouldn't be one of the harder questions. Spotting the +2,+2,+1 pattern is easy. Translating that to Excel is a bit harder.

Comment: You can also copy and paste-special to paste the values only if you want that as your end result (rather than a formula).

Comment: [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) had a pretty wonderful idea about pseudorandom generation: start with any big (for example, 8-digit) number. In every step, square it (you get an around 16-digit number), and take the *middle 8 digit* of the result. It will look *very strange*, although it will be quite logical. :-)

Comment: If you ever find yourself wondering "Can Excel do that?", the answer is "Yes, it can." That's because [Excel is Turing Complete](http://www.felienne.com/archives/2974), which means it's capable of performing ***any*** calculation a computer can do.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Putting my Comp.Sci hat on, that's not actually true. "Turing complete" means that any problem can be converted into an Excel sheet, evaluated in Excel, and then translated back to the solution of that problem. It doesn't say that such translation back and forth can be done within Excel itself.

Comment: @MSalters no. It actually means that Excel can perform any computation that a Turing machine can. You can treat the spreadsheet like a tape.

Comment: @RubberDuck: That's exactly my point. If it treats some cells as tape (and the others have formula's to drive that Turing Machine), the cells in the tape will only take the values of the (finite) alphabet of the Turing Machine, and not other values. And formally speaking, this question assumes that the cell values are unbounded integers.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Excel only recognizes arithmetic patterns.

In your case, you can define a formula and fill it to the needed rows.

`=A1 + IF(MOD(ROW(), 3) = 0, 1, 2)`

Change A1 to the cell where your sequence starts.

In this screen shot below, A1 has the value 14. In A2 I entered this formula

```
=A1 + IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,1,2)
```

And copied it down

[image]

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: I think this is my answer, but It just says #NAME?

Comment: Can you confirm that you enter 14 into A1 and then copy and pasted the formula into A2? And then copied from A2 downards @baswijdenesdotcom?

Comment: Yep: http://imgur.com/a/v94xc

Comment: I suspect it's a language issue. There will be either MOD or ROW equivilant in your native language. What language is your PC set up for? May help http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=nederlands-english.html `MOD` is possibly `REST` and `ROW` is possibly `RIJ` @baswijdenesdotcom

Comment: mine is in dutch, but it isn't working :-(. I checked the website you gave me. It should work with REST / RIJ indeed.

Comment: I got it! IF = ALS, should have known that haha im sorry

Comment: There is a setting in Excel which will make your life of internet support a million times easier: "**Use english function names**"

Comment: Excel internationalises function names? Oh god :(

Comment: @pjc50  As a programmer I too find it horrifying, but programmers aren't Excel's target market.  End users who if not semi-English are unlikely to have memorized a list of English language key words are.  For them writing a formula from scratch localized keywords are a much more user friendly option.  OTOH I have to wonder how hard supporting localized and English key words would've been.  On the gripping hand localization probably dates back to pre-internet times; and my suggestion would be all but guaranteed to break someones spreadsheets somehow if done now.

Comment: @DanNeely I agree that localized function names in Excel might be more suitable for non-programmers, but at least they should convert the names to English internally. I've seen many problems when opening Excel sheets in another locale with different function names and comma/dot as a radix point http://stackoverflow.com/q/19518644/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/13247771/995714

Answer (score 56):

Excel supports arithmetic patterns with step size >1
Fill in the first 3 values, and then use a pattern from there down

1. 14
2. 16
3. 17
4. `=A1+5`

and then copy that down. I.e. A5 becomes `=A2+5` which is indeed 21.

Comment: This is probably the easiest and most intuitive method which is also fairly general.

Comment: sometimes I see a question with multiple answers from the same person. most commonly this is a new user not experienced with the site, without permission to comment. whatever the case may be, 1 (or usually both) of the answers are not particularly good. this is the first time I have seen a double answer where BOTH ANSWERS ARE GOOD AND DECENTLY UPVOTED. mind: blown. rats off to ya, @MSalters

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you start at row 1, it's `=ROUND((ROW()*5+37)/3,0)`

For every 3 rows, you add 5, hence 5/3. The 37 is to get the starting value right (row 1 => value 14). `ROUND` to two digits to see how it works.

Answer (score 9):

I really like the intuition behind the already posted answers but it seems everyone is overlooking the simplest solution built into excel.

- Just type 14 in cell `A1`
- in `A2` type `=A1 + 2`
- in `A3` type `=A2 + 1`
- in `A4` type `=A3 + 2`
- select cells A2, A3 and A4 and drag the fill handle in the bottom right corner to the desired point. Excel will indeed repeat the formulas as typed.

Edit: Just to add, although the OP's question is arithmetic in nature and can be tackled with elegant mathematical solutions, if someone comes across this with any other non-mathematical formulas they want to repeat in this fashion, any conditional math would just clutter and slow down the sheet.